# Lubridate speed up date time operation

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert 04/03/2019 07:22:14 -> 2019-04-03 07:22:14 with lubridate package. My approach works good, but it is very slow:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(DateTimeStamp=replicate(9e5,"04/03/2019 07:22:14"), 
stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(DateTimeStamp_Changed=as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(DateTimeStamp, 
function(item) {
    return(as.character(parse_date_time(paste0(
      as.Date(unlist(strsplit(item," "))[1], "%m/%d/%Y"),
      unlist(strsplit(item," "))[2]
    ), orders="ymd HMS")))
  }))))
```

Is there any way how to speed this up? Thanks for any of your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `ymd_hms()` from the library **lubridate**

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

"04/03/2019 07:22:14" %>%
    fast_strptime(format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') %>% 
    ymd_hms()
# [1] "2019-03-04 07:22:14 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is much faster.